# Java - writeLong method of DataOutputStream and writing hex

Tags: java, hex, file-writing

Currently, I have:

```
outByte.writeInt(0x49492a00); 
outByte.writeInt(0x08000000);
```

But i want to be able to write all of that on the same line. But:

```
outByte.writeLong(0x49492a0008000000)
```

is underlined red in Eclipse, and therefore incorrect. Is it possible to write those two lines all in one with writeLong()?

Comment: "Throws an error" is pretty vague. Could you say *exactly* what happens please?

Comment: "Throws an error" implies a runtime exception. This error is a compile-time error. It would be easier if you copy-and-pasted the exact error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use a `long` literal in your source code, you will need to append `l` or `L` to the constant like this:

```
outByte.writeLong(0x49492a0008000000L)
```